Datatable: How to put sorting on the first header row (by default sorting is put on the second row)
I am having a problem with sorting.
By default it is put on the second header line but I want it on the first and not on the second.
The second header row may seem silly when viewed like this, but in reality I will use this to search for each respective column.
Below is a working example of what is happening to me.


$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    colReorder: true,
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
      var api = this.api(), data;

      // Append footer if it doesn't exist
      if ($('#example').find('tfoot').length ===0) {
        var footer = $('<tfoot><tr><th colspan="6">g</th></tr></tfoot>');
        $('#example').append(footer);
      } 

      // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
      var intVal = function ( i ) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
        typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
      };

      // Total over all pages
      total = api
      .column( 5 )
      .data()
      .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0 );

      // Total over this page
      pageTotal = api
      .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
      .data()
      .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0 );

      // Update footer
      $( '#example tfoot th:eq(0)' ).html(
        '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
      );
    }
  });



} );
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.3/css/colReorder.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.3/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>


        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russell Chavez</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



Can someone please help me?
With initComplete function non working.


$(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: { ......... },
                pageLength: 10,
                searching: true,
                initComplete: function() {
                    this.api()
                        .columns()
                        .every(function() {
                            let column = this;
                            let title = column.header().textContent;

                            // Create input element foot
                            let input = document.createElement('input');
                            input.placeholder = "Search " + title;
                            column.header().replaceChildren(input);

                            var first = document.querySelector("#example .first")
                            var second = document.querySelector("#example .second")
                            first.before(second)

                            // Event listener for user input
                            input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
                                if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                                    column.search(input.value).draw();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                }
            });


        });




You can replace the header elements after you initialize DataTable.


$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    colReorder: true,
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
      var api = this.api(),
        data;

      // Append footer if it doesn't exist
      if ($('#example').find('tfoot').length === 0) {
        var footer = $('<tfoot><tr><th colspan="6">g</th></tr></tfoot>');
        $('#example').append(footer);
      }

      // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
      var intVal = function(i) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
      };

      // Total over all pages
      total = api
        .column(5)
        .data()
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0);

      // Total over this page
      pageTotal = api
        .column(5, {
          page: 'current'
        })
        .data()
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0);

      // Update footer
      $('#example tfoot th:eq(0)').html(
        '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
      );

      // replace header rows
      var first = document.querySelector("#example .first")
      var second = document.querySelector("#example .second")
      first.before(second)

    }
  });



});
.second {
  background: blue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.3/css/colReorder.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.3/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr class="first">
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="second">
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>


      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Russell Chavez</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




I'm using your suggestion but it's not working for me with initComplete. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong? See updated answer above. It behaves exactly as it did in the beginning.

did you add class first and second to the rows? also, take it out of the columns loop: the swap should happen once.

Yes yes, they have been added. So where do you recommend I put them?

I also tried the every method but it still doesn't work
